# How to get Jenkins env variable from Java app?

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I am running integration tests written in Java inside of a Jenkins pipeline.

In my pipeline I am setting the `appium.app.branch` variable(`env.'appium.app.branch' = branch`).
Then I call 'mvn verify'. The problem is that in my Java test code I can't get `appium.app.branch` value. `System.getenv("appium.app.branch")` call retutns `null`.

How to get the value?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`withEnv() {}`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-withenv-code-set-environment-variables) block. Something like this should work

```
node {
  withEnv(["appium.app.branch=${branch}"]) {
    sh 'mvn verify'
  }
}
```

However I am not sure about the variable name, bash for example doesn't support variable names with dots. Try to use some alphanumeric + underscore name like `APPIUM_APP_BRANCH`